# Photoshop designs to Android Screens

Tags: android

I have some screen designs for an Android Mobile app I have developed using Photoshop ... can they be used to develop the screens and if so, how are they converted from psd to android screens?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create .png files by cropping your Photoshop file. Then use this images in your objects (Images or ImageButtons etc.) 
At first you should read how to design interface on Android developer guide http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/index.html

Answer (score 0):

Export the images from any version of Photoshop or other editing software as a flat file in ".png" format.

You can set these images as Android Wallpaper via any number of methods. The easiest may be to email the image to your device and long press on the displayed image and select "Set as Wallpaper".

More complicated solutions involve creating an Android application to set the image on a phone, such as this [Wallpaper Tutorial](http://www.helloandroid.com/tutorials/wallpaper-tutorial-part-2).